# How can I test MongoDB in the app router of Next.js?

Tags: mongodb, next.js, playwright, app-router

I'm using App Router with version 14.1.0 of Next.js. I have defined a very simple page.tsx as follows

```
interface Props {
  params: {
    companyId: string;
  };
}

export default async function SurveyStartingPage({
  params,
}: Props) {
  const { companyId } = params;

  const company = await CompanyModel.findOne({
    _id: companyId,
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{companyId}</div>
      <div>{company?.name}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The CompanyModel is defined using mongoose.

```
import { Schema, model, Model, Document, models } from "mongoose";

export interface ICompany extends Document {
  name: string;
}

type CompanyModelType = Model<ICompany>;

const companySchema = new Schema<ICompany, CompanyModelType>(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export const CompanyModel: CompanyModelType =
  models.Company || model("Company", companySchema);
```

How can I test this component?

I found a way to do this using Playwright at the following URL, but these have the API endpoint URL in them and I can't figure out how to change that part of the URL.

```
import { test, expect } from 'next/experimental/testmode/playwright'

test('/product/shoe', async ({ page, next }) => {
  next.onFetch((request) => {
    if (request.url === 'http://my-db/product/shoe') {
      return new Response(
        JSON.stringify({
          title: 'A shoe',
        }),
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        }
      )
    }
    return 'abort'
  })

  await page.goto('/product/shoe')

  await expect(page.locator('body')).toHaveText(/Shoe/)
})
```

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/src/experimental/testmode/playwright/README.md

Maybe I should not use playwright. Any information would be appreciated.